# Not able to read bus schedule in France

Tags: france, buses

[This pdf file](https://www.tourisme-metabief.com/fileadmin/user_upload/OTMO2L/PDF/Transports/2018_2019_-_TER_FRASNE_VALLORBE.pdf) indicates which bus I should take from Vallorbe to Metabief.

However, as I am not able to read French, can someone kindly help to read the file and pinpoint me to which bus should I take at Vallorbe in order to reach Metabief?

Thanks.

Comment: Google Translate can actually deal with PDFs, though [it doesn't handle this one very well](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tourisme-metabief.com%2Ffileadmin%2Fuser_upload%2FOTMO2L%2FPDF%2FTransports%2F2018_2019_-_TER_FRASNE_VALLORBE.pdf).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Métabief is a village in France. Vallorbe is across the border in Switzerland. Vallorbe is not the primary way to reach Métabief: that would be Frasne, in France, even though it's farther from Métabief. The bus schedule you've found gives you a few more options between Frasne and Métabief than between Vallorbe and Métabief.

Some useful translations for this schedule:

- “Lun à Ven” = Monday to Friday
- “Sam” = Saturdays
- “Dim” = Sundays
- “et fêtes” = and [public holidays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_France)
- “sauf” = except
- “circule” = runs, “ne circule pas” = does not run
- “Horaire en rouge : circule uniquement en période scolaire” = schedule in red: runs only during school periods.
- “Horaire en vert : circule uniquement en période de vacances scolaires” = schedule in green: runs only during [school holidays](https://publicholidays.fr/school-holidays/) (Métabief is in Burgundy, so it's in the *académie de Dijon* which is in zone A).
- CAR = bus
- TER = local train
- TGV = high-speed train
- “ville” or “village” in a stop name = in the town center
- “gare” or “SNCF” = train station (SNCF = French railways; CFF = SBB = Swiss railways)

[Métabief](https://www.tourisme-metabief.com/infos-pratiques/transports.html) is a ski resort. During peak ski season (French winter school holidays), a shuttle bus runs between Frasne and some ski resorts. The rest of the year, there are only a few buses a day.

In a comment, you mention that you're arriving in Geneva on a Sunday. Your best option by public transport would be to take a [train](https://www.sbb.ch/en/home.html) to Frasne and then that bus you found. The train trip to Frasne takes a little under 2 hours with a local train to Lausanne and then a TGV to Frasne. Note that you must book in advance on the TGV.

However the connections aren't good: the buses are scheduled to connect to trains from Paris, not from Lausanne. Chances are that the place where you're staying can pick you up, if not in Geneva, then at least in Vallorbe which is served by Swiss local trains (every hour on Sundays). If you can't get a pick-up in Vallorbe, you can get a [taxi](https://taxis.nosavis.ch/taxi/vaud-24/vallorbe-1337/). It's a small town, so I recommend that you book in advance (maybe from the airport in case your flight is delayed; Swiss trains are very reliable). The [local taxi company](https://www.taxilespierrots.ch/taxi#tarifs) estimates the fare at 44 CHF, and according to [this site](http://www.taxisvallorbe.ch/) they accept cards (in Europe, that means Visa and Mastercard).

Comment: 'There are a few buses a day'. Do you refer to buses between Frasne and Metabief or Vallorbe and Metabief?

Comment: I just realize that in my pdf file, some are empty. What do those empty spaces mean?

Comment: @Idonknow: There are _some_ times in each column of the timetable you show -- but some columns show train connections between Frasne and Paris or Pontarlier, which don't come anywhere near Metabief or Vallorbe.

Comment: @Idonknow You mean empty spaces on a line with a stop? That just means that the bus/train doesn't stop there.

Comment: @Gilles for example, bus 338p1, after 6.15am, there are some empty spaces before reaching next number. I am just curious what hose spaces mean.

Comment: @Idonknow Right, that just means that the bus doesn't stop there. That bus calls at Vaux‐et‐Chantegrue at 6:15 then Labergement‐Sainte‐Marie at 6:23, then at Saint-Antoine at 6:31, etc. It doesn't go through Les Granges-Sainte-Marie, Malbuisson or for that matter Métabief.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for your answer. One more question. In your answer, you suggested to take a train to Frasne and then that bus you found. What do you mean by that bus you found?

Comment: @Idonknow I mean the bus schedule that you link in your question.

Comment: @Gilles I see. Then from Frasne, I can take either 33803, 33805, 33809 or 33813 bus to Métabief, right?

Comment: @Gilles I clicked in the train website you provided in your answer. Everything is in English. How do you do that?

Comment: @Idonknow Only 33803, 33805 or 33813, since you're arriving on a Sunday in June. 33809 is in green so it only runs during school holidays. Regarding the website language, I linked to the English part of the site where available. I edited my answer to add a note about taxis.

Comment: @Gilles I could not obtain any video on how to board bus at Frasne in YouTube. If possible, can you tell me how to board bus at Frasne such as how far it is from train station to bus stop, etc?

Comment: @Idonknow It's a very small town and the bus stops at the station. There's nowhere to get lost.

Answer (score 3):

The right bus appears to be 33802, leaving Vallorbe at 5:53 AM and arriving in Métabief at 6:16 AM. (The second page lists buses going in that direction.)

Remember that that bus only operates Monday through Friday ("Lun à Ven", short for "Lundi à Vendedi"), during school term time ("uniquement en période scolaire").

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by 'second page lists buses going in that direction'? By 'that direction', do you mean from Vallorbe to Metabief?

Comment: By the way, I will reach Vallorbe on 16 June (Sunday) around 11am. So I cannot take the bus in the pdf to Metabief? If this is the case, what are the ways to travel from Vallorbe to Metabief?

Comment: @Idonknow Yes, that is what I mean. As far as finding another way to get there, you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: And operates only during school periods: "Horaire en rouge : circule uniquement en période scolaire."

Comment: @Somewanderingyeti Heh, missed that text. Pardonnez mon français...

Comment: Somehow I doubt that 33802 will be the _route number_ displayed by the bus. It appears rather to be a _departure number_ not for public consumption and possibly even invented by the railways because their timetable-printing system expects everything that moves to have its own number.

Comment: @HenningMakholm 33802 is a service number assigned by SNCF. Indeed, it isn't a route number: it's the number for a specific run of that route at a specific time of the day. And indeed it won't be displayed on the bus.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very specific reason to only take the bus you can also get from Vallorbe to Métabief by taking the train (TGV) to Frasne first and then change to a bus there.

[image]

Comment: Any difference between taking bus and train at Vallorbe? Because it seems that if I take bus at Vallorbe, I will reach Metabief in one go. But if I take train at Vallorbe, then I need to change to bus later.

Comment: Do you mean that since I will be taking train at Geneva Airport, it is better to alight at Frasne and then by bus to Metabief?

Comment: @Idonknow The timetable you've posted doesn't list any convenient bus connections. You could get to Métabief by bus, but only with changing buses inbetween. And it will take you the whole day.

Comment: I thought I can take bus at Vallorbe to Metabief without changing bus?

Comment: @Idonknow See the other answer (the one you've accepted). There is only one connection by bus, running Mon-Fri during school time, leaving Vallorbe at 05:53 in the morning. So sure, if you want to stay in Vallorbe on Sunday that will work as well.

Comment: If the 20-minute bus journey isn't at a convenient time, then wouldn't it be better to take a taxi (20 minutes won't cost a lot) than to make a two-and-a-half journey by train and bus?

Comment: @DavidRicherby One could even walk for 2h :-) Yeah, taking the train to Frasne and the bus back is probably overkill.

Comment: @DavidRicberby are there taxis from Geneva Airport to Metabief? I am sorry if I ask too many questions as this is my first time traveling to Switcherland and go to France.

Comment: @Idonknow: David is suggesting taking a taxi from Vallorbe to Metabief rather than waiting for the twice-a-day-on-weekdays bus.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Do you mean weekend instead of weekdays?

Comment: @Idonknow It's about 100km from Geneva to Metabief, will make an expensive taxi ride. As has been proposed in various answers/comments: Either take the train from Geneva to Frasne and the bus from there; or take the train to Vallorbe and a taxi from there. This will be cross-border from Switzerland to France, so best to inquire beforehand how much this will cost.

Comment: @Idonknow According to the timetable you've posted there are no busses between Valorbe and Metabief on weekends.

Comment: @Idonknow Maybe best to post a new question, explain when exactly you arrive at Geneva, and then ask for options on how to get to Metabief.

Comment: @nohillside good idea. I will do so.

Comment: @Idonknow: I meant "twice a day on weekdays", but when I read closer I see I should have said "_once_ a day on weekdays", because the afternoon bus doesn't stop at Métabief. There are _zero_ buses a day on weekends.